# I can't get secret when I use Spring Cloud Config Server with Hashicorp Vault backend repository

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server

First, I set the bootstrap.yml file of my Spring Cloud Config Server, then start it in my IDEA.

- bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active:
        # this value set can refer to : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/#vault-backend
      - vault

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: "8200"
          host: "127.0.0.1"
          kv-version: 2

server:
  port: 8071
```

then, I execute the following command (this command pulls the 1.13.2 version docker image of Vault):

```
 docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK  -d -p 8200:8200 --name vault -e 'VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot' -e 'VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200' vault
```

next, I set my secret property in Vault Web UI by accessing following url:

```
http://localhost:8200/ui/vault/auth
```

I use `myroot` login, and enable a secret engine (kv) which version is 2, `path` is `licensing-service` .

Next, I set the `path for this secret` is `default` and the `secret data` is `license.vault.property` (key) 、`Welcome to Vault` (value).

After saving, I run the following command line:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/default" -H "X-Config-Token: myroot"
```

But I can't get the secret property, only get the following response:

```
{"name":"licensing-service","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}%
```

Who can tell why? The correct response should be this:

```
{
  "name":"licensing-service",
  "profiles":["default"],
  "label":null,
  "version":null,
  "state":null,
  "propertySources":[
   {
    "name": "vault:licensing-service",
    "source": {

        "license.vault.property": "Welcome to Vault"

    }
   }
  ]
}
```

I expect one person can tell me the reason,why I can not get the expected result?

---

**first update:**

I try another way again in this morning, I use the following `cURL` command, which got the correct response containing my property:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8200/v1/licensing-service/data/default" -H "X-Vault-Token: myroot"
```

the response:

```
{
    "request_id":"718e7a63-990e-3e46-5c94-17404528c824",
    "lease_id":"",
    "renewable":false,
    "lease_duration":0,
    "data":{
        "data":{
            "license.vault.property":"Welcome to Vault"
         },
        "metadata":{
            "created_time":"2023-04-30T05:09:44.840180099Z",
            "custom_metadata":null,
            "deletion_time":"",
            "destroyed":false,
             "version":2
        }
     },
    "wrap_info":null,
    "warnings":null,
    "auth":null
}
```

In this case, it seems like the problem is with Spring Cloud ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the errors in the book(spring microservices in action,second edtion). The secret engine's name corresponds to the `backend` (`spring.cloud.config.server.vault.backend`) property, thus it must be configured in your `bootstrap.yml` file. Furthermore, the secret created under the `licensing-service` secret engine ought to be named `licensing-service` instead of `default`, given that it corresponds to the application's name rather than profiles(`spring.profiles.active`).

If you require the utilization of Hashicorp Vault as a backend repository for Spring Cloud Config Server within multiple environments (for instance, dev, stage, prod), please refer to the following: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/architecture-multiple-environments/26565.

**appendix:**

1. [spring in action, fifth edtion](https://potoyang.gitbook.io/spring-in-action-v5/di-14-zhang-pei-zhi-guan-li/14.5-wei-pei-zhi-de-shu-xing-jia-mi/14.5.2-zai-vault-zhong-cun-chu-mi-ma).
2. you can try `spring.cloud.config.server.vault.scheme=https`, then when you use `curl` command, an error message will be displayed, and you will be able to locate a link similar to `"https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/licensing-service/data/licensing-service`. The first instance of `licensing-service` in this link pertains to the secret engine's name, whereas the second instance of `licensing-service` corresponds to the application or service name.